# Tablesorter expand-child remains open when it's associated toggle row is on previous page after gotoPage clicked

Tags: tablesorter

Ref: Tablesorter

Issue: expand-child element remains visible when select page number clicked

Hi

The problem I'm facing is best described in steps

1.) I have nested tables inside a parent table

2.) I'm using the 'toggle' class on a tr followed by a tr with the class 'expand-child' (structural association) - jquery hides all nested tr's onload

3.) If the hidden tr (expand-child) is clicked open and the outer parent table's (holding the nested table) 'select page number' is clicked the 'expand-child' tr remains open while it's associated toggle tr has moved onto the previous page

I need to pass the associated expand-child tr to the previous page so it can be with it's  associated toggle tr so that it too is not visible until the page it's on is in focus

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution would be to hide all child rows after the pager page changes. Try something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/996/)):

```
$('.tablesorter').on('pageMoved', function(){
    $(this).find('.expand-child td').hide();
});
```

Comment: That's a great fix...!
I made a few adjustments to fit the markup structure. I'm sure the jq selection in the if condition could be more efficient but for now it's a great solution.


$('.tablesorter').on('pageMoved', function(){
  if($(this).parent('div.wrap').get(0).tagName = "div") {
    $(this).find('.expand-child td').hide();
  }
});

Comment: Try `$('div.wrap > .tablesorter').on(...)`

Comment: I couldn't get the above to work possibly because div.wrap is in the markup whereas .tablesorter is injected. My guess is that somehow the adjacent child selector is not honoring the coupling between a hard coded class element and one that's injected or a similar thing is happening with on.

Comment: This is what I went with in the end (thx for the first suggetion):  
  
`$('.tablesorter').on('pageMoved', function (event) {  
if($(this).parent().prop("tagName") != "div") {  
event.stopPropagation();  
} else {  
$(this).find('.expand-child td').hide();
}
})`

Comment: Great! If my answer helped, please check the checkmark next to it to accept it as your answer :)